# tensorflow IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I tried to run a demo of TensorFlow.The MNIST dataset has been download,but there exists one error. Who can tell me what's wrong? Thanks very much! The error detail as follows:

```
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linbinghui/文档/pycode/my_tensorflow_code/test_mnist.py", line 7, in <module>
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py", line 189, in read_data_sets
    local_file = maybe_download(TEST_IMAGES, train_dir, SOURCE_URL + TEST_IMAGES)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 81, in maybe_download
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(source_url, temp_file_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 350, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 836, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is attempting to download https://storage.googleapis.com/cvdf-datasets/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz and failing.  It failed because of "Connection Refused" which generally indicates that the remote end is not running a server on the port you tried to contact it on.

This URL refers a Google storage service.  I was able to successfully download this file.  Either you encountered a transient failure of Google's service, or some intermediary between you and Google caused this problem.

Normally "connection refused" is not caused by anything other than the intended remote end being unavailable (there's a computer there but no specific service).  However, in the face of modern HTTP and HTTPS proxies, DNS redirection and the like, you could very well have encountered some feature of your business/school/home/government internet interdiction.  HTTPS urls can be troubling to the entity hosting your internet service because it represents a private communication channel through which you could download malware or upload secrets.  This troubling nature makes it more likely to be intercepted or redirected or disabled entirely.

I recommend that you troubleshoot this problem with `wget`/`curl` or similar on your machine.  If those work well, consider a small python script with the `requests` package.  Consider also the impact of environment variables on these utilities/libraries.  Try repeating this procedure at network endpoints other than the one you're using.

If you find that the results of repeated tests are unstable even in the same network endpoint, perhaps you're facing local load balancers/proxies or some other transient local failure.  When in doubt, contact your local network support team.

Comment: The code can't download package 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz' .I thought I couldn't visit Google in China.But I download 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz' by the link you gave,and put it in 'MNIST_data'.Then the code downloaded another package 't10k-images-idx1-ubyte.gz',really weird.Anyway,thanks a lot.